# Android Gradle script in multi-module project

Tags: beginner, android, groovy, gradle

I have a multi-module Android project built by Gradle with the new Android-plugin 0.10+.

All modules are mainly configured from the root project.

I've enable the new code coverage feature. The major problem is that only some modules contain test code and when I enable code coverage on modules that don't contain test code, it fails.

I would like to avoid enabling code-coverage in each module `build.gradle` file so that when someone add test code in a module that wasn't tested, there is no need to modify the `build.gradle`.

I ended up with the following code where code coverage is enabled only when the `androidTest` `sourceSet` contains at least one .java source file. It works as expected, but I'm wondering if there is a nicer way of doing this.

Here is the relevant portion of the root project `build.gradle` script:

```
configure(subprojects.findAll()) {
    if(it.name.equals('MyApp')){
        apply plugin: 'android'
    }else{
        apply plugin: 'android-library'
    }

    android {
        ...
        //my question is really about the follong 4 lines :
        //is there a simpler way to get java source file count in the androidTest sourceSet ?
        def androidTestJavaSourceFileCount = 0
        sourceSets.androidTest.allJava.each {
            androidTestJavaSourceFileCount ++
        }
        println("androidTestJavaSourceFileCount in androidTest for module $project.name : $androidTestJavaSourceFileCount")
        buildTypes {
            debug {
                testCoverageEnabled = androidTestJavaSourceFileCount > 0
            }
        }

        jacoco {
            version = '0.6.2.201302030002'
        }

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
           }
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what we have here:

```
sourceSets.androidTest.allJava.each {
    ...
}
```

- `sourceSets` leads to [SourceSetContainer](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/SourceSetContainer.html)
- `.androidTest` leads to a single [SourceSet](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html)
- `.allJava` leads to [the `allJava` property on a SourceSet](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet:allJava) which leads to a [SourceDirectorySet](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/SourceDirectorySet.html)

Now, while there is not a `.size()` method or anything like it in SourceDirectorySet, or any of the super interfaces of that, there is some Groovy magic that [provides a `.size()` method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#size(java.lang.Iterable)) for all `Iterable`s.

This means that you should be able to do the following:

```
def androidTestJavaSourceFileCount = sourceSets.androidTest.allJava.size()
```

Don't be fooled by this one-liner though, the source of the `Iterable.size()` method is:

```
public static int size(Iterable self) {
    return size(self.iterator());
}
```

which calls:

```
public static int size(Iterator self) {
    int count = 0;
    while (self.hasNext()) {
        self.next();
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

So it will do the same thing as your previous code did, but it will clean up your part of the code.